# No sound via HDMI on Bootcamp

Tags: macos, audio, hdmi, boot-camp

I have a 2015 Macbook Air running Windows 10 on bootcamp. Everything works great except for sound via HDMI. When I plug in the HDMI cable no new sound device shows up when I check "Playback Devices" in Win10. HDMI works fine for video.

I suspect I need a driver to let me send sound through the HDMI cable as well as video - but which driver?

Comment: I noticed that "Intel Display Audio" shows up under device manager when I have HDMI plugged in. I uninstalled that driver and rebooted Windows, it reinstalled it automatically and now my issue is fixed.

Comment: Macbook Pro 2016 here with no display port audio over thunderbolt. `Sound, video.../Intel Display Audio` was not showing up in the Device Manager. I had to uninstall all `System devices/High Definition Audio Controller`s. Even those not exclamation marked. They automatically reinstalled instantly and it worked.